# GPIO state monitoring via command line?

Tags: gpio

I know it's possible to write and read GPIO values using the command line:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio0/value
```

for example, puts the GPIO 0 pin on high.

Now, for reading, you use `cat`. However, this restricts me to polling and does not prevent me from missing a state inbetween poll events.

Is there a way for me to register some kind of listener via the command line as you would with RPIO in Python?

I want to listen for value changes without polling. I assume polling extremely quickly (to make missing a state less likely) is not very healthy either?

There is a target called `/sys/class/gpio/gpio../uevent` but I don't know what it is for.

Comment: Why not use a Python/C/C++/Perl/<insert language here> implementation that implements Interrupts, and just sits in the background?

Comment: I wanted my own very simple library for satisfaction's sake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt
some of the GPIO can be configured as interrupt generating.

> "value" ... reads as either 0 (low) or 1 (high). If the GPIO
>           is configured as an output, this value may be written;
>           any nonzero value is treated as high.
>
> If the pin can be configured as interrupt-generating interrupt
>           and if it has been configured to generate interrupts (see the
>           description of "edge"), you can poll(2) on that file and
>           poll(2) will return whenever the interrupt was triggered. If
>           you use poll(2), set the events POLLPRI and POLLERR. If you
>           use select(2), set the file descriptor in exceptfds. After
>           poll(2) returns, either lseek(2) to the beginning of the sysfs
>           file and read the new value or close the file and re-open it
>           to read the value.
>
> "edge" ... reads as either "none", "rising", "falling", or
>           "both". Write these strings to select the signal edge(s)
>           that will make poll(2) on the "value" file return.
>
> This file exists only if the pin can be configured as an
>           interrupt generating input pin.

Should be like this..

```
echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo rising > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/edge
```

Based on your comment, I recommend to check [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) where a [Java wrapper](https://github.com/mattjlewis/diozero) exists. The library​ is maintained by another user of this community. The wrapper is also well documented. I think with this you can develop bit more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much, because I'm doing stuff in Java, I was able to manipulate the edge target and use a WatchService to detect changes and it works amazingly well!

Comment: @Limnic, I've updated the answer. The information that you want to use this in Java was not missing before :)

Comment: After a bit of experimenting, it seems like pure java code to manage GPIO is too hard for my raspberry pi zero. It's under 100% cpu load pretty much after the tiniest loop. There can probably be optimizations but I thought "since all other libraries fall back to native calls, I'll just use [PI4J](http://pi4j.com)." And even though I don't like the API as much, it performs a lot better haha :)